# Rails 2 and mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Do you aware of any requirements of Rails 2.3.5 in terms of mysql.
Will Rails 2.3.5 work with mysql 5.5.
What's the below bound, what's the youngest version of mysql compatible with Rails 2.3.5.

Thanks!

Comment: I know this isn't an answer, but I would recommend upgrading to Rails 3. Rails 2.3.5 is getting just a little outdated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm currently working on a project with mysql server version 5.5.10 running along with rails 2.3.14, using the gem mysql2 0.2.11.

Due to the fact that you'll use rails < 3.1 and assuming that you'll use mysql2 "=0.2.18" gem ([due to ActiveRecord compatibilities](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2), ActiveRecord section @ README.md) I assume that you'll be perfectly fine with mysql 5.5 since it is out since December 2009 and this version of mysql2 is from December 2011.

I belive you'll have no problems with 5.5.20.